# ng-change not working, Data not loading after ng-change

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, hibernate

I added an `data-ng-change='getSubjectsClasswise(classBean.class_id);'` in class `<select>` tag, but subjects are not loading at subject `<select>` tag.

Everything looks fine, not getting the issue, please help me out.

**JSP:**

```
<div data-ng-controller='ChapterController'>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Select Class * :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select data-ng-model='classBean.class_id' data-ng-change='getSubjectsClasswise(classBean.class_id);'  class="form-control" name='stdClass' required>
                    <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
                    <option data-ng-repeat='c in clss' value="{{ c.class_id}}">{{ c.class_name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Select Subject * :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select data-ng-model='sid' class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
                    <option data-ng-repeat='s in subss' value="{{ s.sid}}">{{ s.subject_name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-right">
        <button type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS Controller:**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("CareerTurn");
app.controller('ChapterController', function($scope, $http, $location, $window, AdminService) {

getClasses();

function getClasses() {
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:8015/CareerTurn/adm/getClasses.do'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.clss = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
    });
}

$scope.getSubjectsClasswise = function(class_id) {
    alert(class_id);
    var URL ='http://localhost:8015/CareerTurn/adm/getClasswiseSubjects.do';
    $http.post(URL,class_id).success(function(response){
        $scope.subss = response.data;
    }).error(function(reponse){
        alert('error');
    });
}
```

});

**Java Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getClasswiseSubjects.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<SubjectBean> getClasswiseSubjects(@RequestBody int class_ids) {
    return getAdminService().getClasswiseSubjects(class_ids);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/getClasses.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<ClassBean> getClasses() {
    return getAdminService().getClasses();
}
```

**DaoImpl:**

```
@Override
public List<ClassBean> getClasses() {
    try{
        String sql="from ClassBean";
        query = em.createQuery(sql);
        return query.getResultList();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<SubjectBean> getClasswiseSubjects(int class_id) {
    try{
        query = em.createQuery("from SubjectBean sb where sb.classBean.class_id=:class_id");
        query.setParameter("class_id", class_id);
        List<SubjectBean> subs = query.getResultList();
        return subs;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Console:**

```
Hibernate: select classbean0_.class_id as class1_1_, classbean0_.class_createdate as class2_1_, classbean0_.class_createdby as class3_1_, classbean0_.class_name as class4_1_ from exam_class classbean0_
Hibernate: select subjectbea0_.sid as sid26_, subjectbea0_.class_id as class6_26_, subjectbea0_.subject_code as subject2_26_, subjectbea0_.subject_createdate as subject3_26_, subjectbea0_.subject_createdby as subject4_26_, subjectbea0_.subject_name as subject5_26_ from subjects_tbl subjectbea0_ where subjectbea0_.class_id=?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `response.data` do just `response`

```
.success(function(response){
        $scope.subss = response;
    }).error(function(reponse){
        alert('error');
    });
```